# is it possible to remove calls to ecall?

Tags: c, embedded, system-calls, riscv32

I am compiling for a riscv cv32(e40s).

With my configuration, every call to `rand()` (or `time()` for instance), generates an `ecall` instruction, which means syscalls have to be implemented.

But what I don't understand is : what if I want to be in baremetal?
the syscall shouldn't be raised, should it?

I would like my program to not generate an `ecall` instruction but I don't know If this is possible.

I understand that for it to work, there should be in the toolchain a implementation of `rand()` that does not uses the system, shouldn't it?

hope this question makes sense.

Comment: Why should your tool chain provide these functions? It cannot know your hardware, for example to implement `time()`. You need to implement these functions yourself.

Comment: Buliding programs for an operating system is very different from building code for bare metal. You must either use completely different tools or at least tell your tool chain that there is no OS available. Just looking at the generated code for one version and expect it to work in different configurations is not very useful

Comment: `what if I want to be in baremetal?` Then you have to change "your configuration", i.e. use a different implementation of `rand()` and `time()`, that do not do a syscall, instead execute some code. Like for example use Newlib standard C library.